# Replace multiple columns by head string into one column

Tags: r

I want to replace multiple columns of a data frame by one column each for each group whereas I also want to change the numbers. Example:

```
  A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3
1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  1  0  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
4  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

I want to sort this data frame by it's headers meaning I only want one column "A" instead of 4 here and only column "B" instead of 3 here. The numbers should change with the following pattern: If you are in group "A2" and the observation has the number "1" it should be changed into a "2" instead. If you are in group "A3" and the observation has the number "1" it should be changed into a "3" instead. The end result should be that I want to contain the highest number in that specific column and row (if I have 3 "1"s in my row and group, the number which is going to replace all of them is going to be the one of the highest group)
If the number is 0 then nothing changes. Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
  A B
1 4 1
2 4 3
3 4 3
4 3 3
5 0 2
```

How can I replace all of these groups by a single column each? (one column for each group)

So far I've tried a lot with the function unite(data= testdata, col= "A") for example, but doing this manually would take too long. There has to be a better way, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the shape of your frame is always A1A2A3A4B1B2B3B4C1C2C3C4 and so on ? ( Are column fixed)

Comment: Sure of course! So one group name example would be AFIK. So the first column name would be AFIK. The second one "AFIK_01". The third one "AFIK_02" and so on. The next variable would then be in the column after this group is finished. Let's say "AFIK_05". Next column: "BKE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
 "A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3
1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  1  0  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
4  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0")

myfu <- function(x) if (any(x)) max(which(x)) else 0

new <- data.frame(
 A=apply(dat[, 1:4]==1, 1, myfu),
 B=apply(dat[, 5:7]==1, 1, myfu))
new
```

A more general solution:

```
new2 <- data.frame(
  A=apply(dat[, grepl("^A", names(dat))]==1, 1, myfu),
  B=apply(dat[, grepl("^B", names(dat))]==1, 1, myfu))
new2
```

Comment: Thanks! But suppose that I didn't want to choose the columns manually but by choosing them by their string automatically. How would I proceed then?

Comment: you can do `grepl()` over the names of your dataframe to get logical index vectors, see my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, upvoted it. Thanks! Suppose now that I want to shift my data. So insteaed of "0" and "1" I now have plenty of "3" and "4"s in my data. And I just wanted to fish out the indice of the column "4". What do I have to do then?

Comment: You have to do `apply(dat[, ...]==4, 1, myfu)` BTW: accepting and upvoting is not the same.

Comment: Oh, gotcha! Thanks. I never did it before, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is in a data.frame called `df1` this works in Base-R

```
df1 <- t(df1)*as.numeric(regmatches(colnames(df1), regexpr("\\d+$", colnames(df1))))
df1 <- split(as.data.frame(df1),sub("\\d+$","",row.names(df1)))
df1 <- sapply(df1, apply, 2, max)
```

output:

```
> df1
  A B
1 4 1
2 4 3
3 4 3
4 3 3
5 0 2
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice solution, however the letters A and B are just codenames for really long words. Within a group the name starts with that long word that differs from other groups. How would I substitute that [A-Z] with this knowledge now?

Comment: You could try replacing `[A-Z]` with `.*` which means any length of any character. Could you provide an example of the group names?

Comment: @NotSoSmart97 I've edited the answer to make it more robust, Now it will use the end numbers of the string.

Comment: Sure of course! So one group name example would be AFIK. So the first column name would be AFIK. The second one "AFIK_01". The third one "AFIK_02" and so on. The next variable would then be in the column after this group is finished. Let's say "AFIK_05". Next column: "BKE"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code like below

```
dfout <- as.data.frame(
    lapply(
        split.default(df, gsub("\\d+$", "", names(df))),
        function(v) max.col(v, ties.method = "last") * +(rowSums(v) >= 1)
    )
)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  A B
1 4 1
2 4 3
3 4 3
4 3 3
5 0 2
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), A2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), A3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), A4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), B1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), B3 = c(0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",
"3", "4", "5"))
```